# replace a character from a string that is in between first and second search using sed or awk

Tags: sed, awk

I need to replace `_` (underscore) with `?` (question mark) in a file containing email addresses.

The file looks like below:

```
EFT_020034-E015133  20140624    /ACC/EMAIL+test_1@mysite.com         SHR    END 
EFT_020034-E015133  20140624    /ACC/EMAIL+test_123_abc@yoursite.net     SHR    END
EFT_020034-E015133  20140624    /ACC/EMAIL+test_456@theirsite.com        SHR    END
```

The expected output is:

```
EFT_020034-E015133  20140624    /ACC/EMAIL+test?1@mysite.com         SHR    END 
EFT_020034-E015133  20140624    /ACC/EMAIL+test?123?abc@yoursite.net     SHR    END
EFT_020034-E015133  20140624    /ACC/EMAIL+test?456@theirsite.com        SHR    END
```

How can I do this in **sed** or **awk** without affecting other underscores and only the underscore between `EMAIL+` (constant) and `SHR` (constant). The changed content should be saved in a new file.

Answer (score 4):

awk will do this:

```
$ awk '{ gsub("_", "?", $3) ; print }' < data
EFT_020034-E015133 20140624 /ACC/EMAIL+test?1@mysite.com SHR END
EFT_020034-E015133 20140624 /ACC/EMAIL+test?123?abc@yoursite.net SHR END
EFT_020034-E015133 20140624 /ACC/EMAIL+test?456@theirsite.com SHR END
```

The email addresses are in field 3, so we replace `_` with `?` in field 3 only, including when there is more than one `_`, using [`gsub`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#String-Functions).

Comment: Note that is replaces sequences of blanks with a single space character and removes the leading and trailing blanks.

Comment: Thank you Michael. It works on my example file. However, when I test it in actual file where the email is located at field 20 or above, nothing happens on the result. Also, I test it using field 1 to replace EFT_ with EFT?, it only works on the first line. Is it due to unix/dos line terminator? Thanks

Comment: @user73549: Line terminators could cause the second part. You can set the RS variable inside the awk script to change the record (line) separator. awk keeps numbering the records indefinitely, so I don't know about the other part. I suspect that your idea of which field the address is in doesn't match awk's - you can set the field separator with the -F command-line option, or try replacing the field value entirely with $23 = "X" to see what it thinks.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I see that line terminator causes my script to misbehave in my subject text file.   Thank you everyone. I learned a lot.

Comment: to add, the text file has CRLF and LF when I view in viewer including the whitespaces and terminator.

Answer (score 3):

With `sed` you could do:

```
sed -e :1 -e 's/_\([^+]*@\)/?\1/;t1'
```

That is replace `_` followed by a sequence of non-`+` characters followed by `@` with `?` with the sequence of character, and repeat the process as long as it matches.

Or to do it only between `EMAIL+` and `SHR`:

```
sed -e :1 -e 's/\(EMAIL+.*\)_\(.*SHR\)/\1?\2/;t1'
```

If you want to only consider the lines that start with `^EFT`, you can add a `-e '/^EFT/!b'` to leave alone those that don't like:

```
sed -e '/^EFT/!b' -e :1 -e 's/\(EMAIL+.*\)_\(.*SHR\)/\1?\2/;t1'
```

Note that for an input like:

```
EFT EMAIL+ foo_bar SHR bar_baz EMAIL+ SHR
```

Both underscores will be replaced because they're both between an `EMAIL+` and a `SHR`.

To avoid that, you could do something like:

```
sed '
  /^EFT/!b # leave the non-EFT lines alone (branch out)
  s/%/%p/g; s/</%l/g; s/>/%r/g; # escape the <>% characters with %
  s/EMAIL+/</g; s/SHR/>/g; # replace EMAIL+ and SHR with < and >
  :1
  s/\(<[^<>]*\)_\([^<>]*>\)/\1?\2/; t1
  s/</EMAIL+/g; s/>/SHR/g; # restore EMAIL+ and SHR
  s/%r/>/g; s/%l/</g; s/%p/%/g; # restore the escaped <>%'
```

Comment: I also added ^EFT to specify the beginning of line at search field -   sed -e :1 -e 's/\(^EFT.*EMAIL+.*\)_\(.*SHR\)/\1?\2/;t1'

Comment: Thank you so much. I actually use your second script and it solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/.*EMAIL+\(.*\)SHR.*/{
    h;s//\1/;y/_/?/;G
    s/\(.*\)\n\(.*EMAIL+\).*SHR/\2\1SHR/}'
```

That should do the job pretty reliably - it will replace all `_` with `?` between the last `EMAIL+` occurring on a line and the last `SHR` to occur on same and only on those lines containing both strings.