# String replacement in file

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have the following file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--Generated by crowdin.net-->
  <string name="test" >- test</string>
  <string name="test" >test-test</string>
  <string name="test" >test - test</string>
```

and I would like to replace the `en dash` with its unicode value, but not all of them, just the one in the `string` tag

I run several `sed` with different regex, but I couldn't figured it out. One of those was

```
sed -i.bak "s/-[^-\<\>0-9]/\&#8211\;/g" strings.xml
```

the output was:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-&#8211;enerated by-->
  <string name="test" >&#8211;test</string>
  <string name="test2" >test&#8211;est</string>
  <string name="test3" >test &#8211;test</string>
```

my problem is that is also replacing *empty spaces* and the *first char* of the second word. I have not that big experience with `regex` and `sed`. Could you please explain me what I am doing wrong?

Note: I'm using OSX.

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/139081/22565

Comment: Take a look at www.rubular.com and plug in your regex expression and XML code. As you know, you do need to tweak your regex code but that website is useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a recent (for `\K` and `s///r`) `perl` and assuming your `<string>` tags don't nest:

```
perl -0777 -pi.bak -e's{<string.*?>\K.*?(?=</string>)}{$&=~s/-/&#8211;/rg}ges' file.xml
```

- `-0777`: *slurp mode*: handle the whole file at once (to allow `<string>` tags to span several lines).
- `-p`: `sed` mode
- `-i.bak`: in-place editing with `.bak` extension (BTW, that's where some `sed` implementations got that idea from)
- `s{...}{...}ges`: substitute globally (`g`), where `.` matches newline characters as well (`s`), and treat the replacement as `perl` code to execute (`e`).
- `<string.*?>\K.*?</string>`: match from `<string...>` to `</string>` but don't include the tags themselves in the part that is *matched* (`\K` defines where the *matched* portion starts, and `(?=...)` is a look-ahead operator that only *checks* if `</string>` is there, but doesn't include it in the match).
- `$&=~s/.../.../rg`. Do the substitution on the *matched* part (`$&`). The `r` flag is to actually not modify `$&` but return the substituted string.

Comment: Nice! Why do you say this won't work on nested tags? It does on my system.

Comment: @terdon, it won't replace the `-` in `<string><string></string>-</string>`

Comment: Ah, yes. I saw it would work on `<string>-<string>-</string></string>` and assumed.

Answer (score 3):

Phew, after some time I got it. This is a naive solution. [terdon's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/140149/72471) is more correct and you should use his though :).

```
sed -Ei.bak "s/(.*<string[^>]*\")(.*)-(.*)/\1\2\&#8211;\3/g" strings.xml
```

I am using [Backreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10874111/3739455) to refer back to a previously matched string. These are `\1` `\2` etc.

In this case sed should match following groups:

- `(.*<string[^>]*\")` - any characters followed by a string tag opening until a quote `"`. **Group 1**
- `(.*)` - anything after the `"` (including right now `>`) until group 3. **Group 2**
- `-` the matching dash
- `(.*)` - anything after the matching dash **Group 3**

Then I replace it with the previously matched groups and the dash HTML value `&#8211;`, by using `\n` with `n` as the reference to group `n`.

#### Problems:

I currently try to fix some problems, so please cope with me:

1. Group 1 matches also `dsfjpasj<string`
2. Group 1 should include the string tag ending character `>`
3. As terdon points out: "this won't work for cases where you have `>1 -` or nested tags or tags spanning multiple lines"

#### Read more:

http://toytoygogie.blogspot.de/2010/02/using-sed-with-backreference-as.html

Comment: Note that the format for `-i` is different for non-GNU `sed` (the OP is on OSX). Also, this won't work for cases where you have >1 `-` or nested tags or tags spanning multiple lines.

Comment: @terdon, that `-Ei.bak` syntax will work with FreeBSD/OSX `sed`. The difference is that the backup extension is optional in GNU `sed` (and has to be `-i.bak`, not `-i .back`) while it's required in FreeBSD/OSX (where both `-i.back` and `-i .back` are allowed). But here, since it's provided and is not in the form `-i .back`, it will work with both GNU and FreeBSD/OSX `sed`.

Comment: two more questions: It would be much effort make it works for the case with more than 1 "-"? If I would like to replace em dash, can I simply change from  (.*)-(.*) to (.*)--(.*) ?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to replace all cases (three in your example) of `-` within `<strng></string>` tags and only those cases. If so, these approaches should work **assuming your XML is sane**:

1. Use a regular expression and a simple tool like `sed`

   ```
   sed 's/\(<string[^>]*>[^-]*\)-\([^-]*<\/string\)/\1\&#8211;\2/' file.xml
   ```
2. If your file is *always* like the example above and you can be sure that your tags will always be `<string name="test" ></string>`, you can use [lookbehinds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

   ```
   perl -pe 's/(?<=<string name="test" >)([^<]*?)-([^<]*)/$1&#8211;$2/g' file.xml
   ```
3. None of the above will work if you have more than a single `-` within the tags. To deal with such cases, you can write a simple little script that checks whether we're within `<string></string>` tags. This should also deal with nested tags.

   ```perl
   perl -F'<' -lane 'for($i=0;$i<=$#F;$i++){
       $a++ if $F[$i]=~/^string/; 
       $F[$i]=~s/-/&#8211;/g if $a>0; 
       $a-- if $F[$i]=~/^\/string/
   } print join "<",@F' file.xml
   ```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I tried the lookbehind solution but it looks like is not supported/implemented in sed osx

Comment: @blackbelt the lookbehind example is using `perl`, not `sed`. As far as I know, `sed` does not support lookarounds.

Comment: @blackbelt you're welcome :). I suggest you accept Stephane's answer below, it is simpler than mine yet still works for multiline, (some) nested tags and multiple `-` cases.